# Javascript ouptut questions

Tags: javascript, output

I was practicing some Javascript Output questions and came across a question which I am unable to understand the output. Here is the code:

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

what will be the value of foo.x ?

I thought it will give as {n: 2, x: {n: 2, x.....}}.
But it's value is undefined. Can anyone explain to me why it's value is coming as undefined

Comment: @JSONaLeo if it returns nothing then, why bar =  `{n: 1, x: {n:2} }` ?

Comment: Wow weird yeah that makes no sense to me

Comment: check out @bmceldowney's answer, seems to have a pretty good grasp on this

Comment: @JSONaLeo assignment operator always returns value. Pls refer assignment operator here - http://javascript.info/operators

Answer (score 4):

`foo` is just a reference to an object.

The line `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};` happens in sequence from left to right. Here are the steps that occur in sequence:

1. `foo.x` is given the value of `foo`, which is a reference an object with an `n` property equal to 1.
2. `foo` then gets assigned to a new object, `{n: 2}`. Since `foo` now references a new object that has no `x` property then `foo.x` is undefined.

But because `bar` is a reference to the original `foo` object (before it was reassigned) then the original object still exists in memory. This is why the `bar` object has both `x` and `n` properties.

Comment: Thanks for teaching us something new. JS is full of surprises

Comment: Thanks, @bmceldowney for explaining the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure about the direction though, If you try it with numbers where there's no references, It goes right to left.

Comment: @zohirSalak - Yes I tried wit number it went right to left, that's why I post this question here. If you have any better explanation for this Pls share with us

Comment: @PriyanshuAgarwal Can you give me an example of using numbers? Numbers can't have properties (so `var foo = 3; foo.x = 2;` just results in `foo = 3` and `foo.x = undefined`) so the example isn't really valid.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

Define a car and name it `foo`

Define sign named `bar` that refers to the car named `foo`

Define a `seat` (foo.x) that you want to be inside the car named `foo` by redefining the car named `foo` and making the seat the same as the car.

---

What you've (essentially) done here is:

1. Create the object
2. Add a property to the object
3. Overwrite what you just created

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a shorthand assignment, to assign multiple variables to the same value in one line.

This is a bit confusing because we're dealing with references.

```
var foo = {n:2}
```

1. foo is a label or a name to that object so we can use it.
2. `{n:2}` is the object we're dealing with, in this example we gonna call it `TheObject` we can use bar but for simplicity sake forget that bar references that object

---

```
var bar = foo;
```

1. this means we're assigning a second name to the very same object.

---

So far everything is clear, hopefully now on this line :

```
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

What's happening here is we're assigning foo.x and foo a new object `{n:2}`,
we telling foo to point to this new object however foo.x is a bit special, it is not whatever foo points to, but `TheObject` our old object.

This is because this is one line operation, when we said `foo` this is just the label/name `foo.x` is `TheObject.x`

## OP's example

```js
var foo = {
  n: 1
};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {
  n: 2
};
console.log(foo)
console.log(bar)
```

## Test example

```js
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
// bar references the first object
// we didn't touche bar so we're good to test with it
bar.x = foo = {n: 2};
console.log(foo)
console.log(bar)
```

sorry if the explanation is a bit wonky, words and my thoughts don't go so well.